# Returning back to main function from c or cpp series of sub functions

Tags: c++

I wounder if there is any way to cancel execution of a function and return back to the caller from a sub - sub function? 
Like in the assembly when you can do a pop from the stack address and make a return .. by that you can ignore the first return address to the previous address. 
I have a hard time to find out a way to stop executing a piece of code when some error happens in a function which might be three way under the main function.. and return back to the main. 
Like when you linux kernel or Windows command prompt run a program and ctrl-C stop the execution and return back to the shell.

Editing the original question:

My solution at the moment is like below (It is not clean): 
What I use at the moment is: I have three macros. I use them in the beginning of all functions. But this costs me memory, speed and the flash of the Microcontroller

```
#define STOP_CODE_EXECUTION_MINUS   if(StopExecution==1) return -1;
#define STOP_CODE_EXECUTION         if(StopExecution==1) return;
#define STOP_CODE_EXECUTION_NULL    if(StopExecution==1) return 0;
```

I choose the version that is suitable of the type of the function (void, int or string). I change the (StopExecution) whenever I get a problem in the OS I have. But if you have been using assembly, you know that you can pop/return to remove addresses from the stack and return back to the original caller (for ex. main). 
My question form the beginning was about that. Is there a way to do the same using c/c++ code? 
But, people here have PHD in programming and you have to ask them in that level.
never mind. I just added that to make it more clear for those who really cared and wanted to help thanks.

Comment: Use exceptions?

Comment: do you have any code you could show us?

Comment: You can use exceptions *if* it's to handle unusual errors. If your function is expected to fail routinely, you probably want to do something with it's return type or value.

Comment: Okay, that does sound like a reasonable use case for C++ exceptions.

Comment: If you leave the question as it was it might be reopened, given enough open votes. Flagging is not about hindering people from asking questions, but to halt the question until a 'fix' or revision is added. Also, you got an answer before it was closed.

Comment: @KuMu I'm not sure what you mean. You've got an answer below. You can engage in a discussion in the comment section on the answer if it's not what you were looking for. I reverted back to your original question because the edit no longer made it a question. And to clarify, the question is not banned. It is just no longer open to new answers until you address the critique in the comments. Some people seemed to believe that you were looking for "exception handling" and thus closed the question until you further clarify whether that's true or you meant something else.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes. You can achieve something like that using techniques like `longjmp`.

In practice, however, it is really much easier, better (not to mention memory-safe in C++!) to solve the problem in another way. For example, you could use exceptions (in C++) or return error codes.

You would then have code like that (C example):

```
int some_failing_function() {
  if(failure) { return 1; }
  return 0;
}
int some_function() {
  if(some_failing_function() == 1) {
    return 1; /* return early and let caller know that we failed */
  }
  /* continue normally */
}
int main() {
  if(some_function() == 1) {
    fputs("failure!\n", stderr);
  }
}
```

Update: If that becomes too complicated for you, you can use exceptions. You `throw` an exception when there is an error and you can later `catch` it:

```
#include <stdexcept>
void some_failing_function() {
  if(failure) { throw std::logic_error("something"); }
}
int some_function() {
  /* just use a normal function call here */      
  some_failing_function();
  /* continue normally */
}
int main() {
  try {
    some_function();
  } catch(std::exception& e) {
    fputs("failure!\n", stderr);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. Modern operating systems don't execute programs like programs would jump into functions. Rather, since programs are running concurrently (as processes), they just stop the execution of a specific process when it's killed.

Comment: C++ will call destructors for local variables whenever exiting a scope by returning or by exception. So if you correctly use RAII principles, this will make sure you don't have leaks.

Comment: @aschepler: Good point. I added that to the answer.

Comment: `longjmp` doesn't unwind. It's pretty hard to use it in a way that doesn't wreck the state of your program. Basically every function in the call stack needs to be aware of the possible jump and be written accordingly. For example, you basically can't allocate dynamically or use objects that might allocate dynamically internally like containers.

Comment: You could alternatively use exceptions. I'll edit my answer accordingly.